# Populate web form using Flex/AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I need to load a page within a Flex based AIR desktop app, then populate certain fields on the page. I am trying to use an HTML control to load the page, but I can't figure out how to interact with DOM elements. Is there another way to do this?

Any pointers or help would be most appreciated!

Thanks,

rw

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post a JSFiddle so we can see your work in progress and help assist you to get an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers - sorry for the late response, I didn't get notified via email, which I am sure is my bad....

So, I have gotten this working. Specifically, I am opening a page, populating fields in a form, submitting the form, then collecting the results. This needs much fleshing out, but the basic concept works:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
private function init(e:Event):void
        {
            htmlCont.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, htmlComplete);
            htmlCont.location="https://www.targetsite.com/pagewithform.html" 

        }
private function htmlComplete(event:Event):void
        {   
            htmlCont.domWindow.document.getElementById("fieldToFill01").value = textInput.text;
            htmlCont.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, htmlComplete);
            //After new page is loaded, trigger function to get data
            htmlCont.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getResult);
            //Use htmlElement.htmlLoader to access DOM click() function.
            htmlCont.htmlLoader.window.document.getElementById("ButtonID").click();


        }                  
private function getResult(e:Event):void
        {
          //Getting all <p> tags for example
          var returnedArray = htmlCont.htmlLoader.window.document.getElementsByTagName("p");
          //Different grabs of the content of a <p> tag.
          trace(returnedArray[0].innerHTML);
          trace(returnedArray[0].innerText);
          trace(returnedArray[0].textContent);
}
</fx:Script>
<!-- Inside your Application somewhere -->
<mx:HTML id="htmlCont" width="100%" height="100%" y="100"/>
```

Again, there is a lot more to be done with this, and I think I will have some regex questions soon as the formatting of my html target page leaves a lot to be desired!

Thanks for the input, sorry again for bad form in not responding.

rw

Comment: Odd choice to downvote 2 years later, especially as this code works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with passing parameters from the Flex / Air app as url variables then in the HTML page (loaded with stagewebview in as3) retrieve those individual data elements using a server side technology (php, asp, etc.) then use javascript to take those values and set them as values for specific fields on the page.

I've used it both ways so for instance the html page can invoke url calls that are monitored by the flex / air app and in as3 I can watch for specific url variables (i.e. when url change is detected) that can trigger any type of action I want to happen in as3, and in the other direction the flex / air app can send data and commands/triggers to the HTML page as well.

AS3 StageWebViewBridge looks really powerful, but I havent pushed myself to get to all the benefits of it yet, I've just used standard StageWebView to suit my needs.  Good luck with your project and let me know if you have any other questions with this.